# jQuery function when one list item has the active class, I want all other list items to automatically not have the active class ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My webpage is at http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/status

All the HTML, CSS and jQuery code + images are available there for anyone to access.

My issue is that currently the jQuery code I have only makes the active states toggle in the list items. What I want is that one list item becomes active(active class) when clicked, all others must have the active class removed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I follow what you want to do, but this code will remove the active class from all other siblings and toggle the current one so there is never more than one item with the active class.

```
$(function() {
    $('#status li').click(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        self.siblings().removeClass('active');
        self.toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

If what you want is that the currently clicked item becomes active and all others become unactive, then you don't want to use toggleClass at all.  You can do that more simply with this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#status li').click(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        self.siblings().removeClass('active');
        self.addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: this is good too. Just one issue, when you click on the active element itself, it also removes the class for that element too. That was not what I wanted. Thanks for taking the time though :)

Comment: As I said, your question wasn't completely clear to me.  If what you want is that the currently clicked item becomes active and all others get the active class removed, then I added a second example to my answer that will do that.  Your code was using toggleClass so I thought that was what you wanted, but I guess not.

Comment: Thanks ! This is exactly what I wanted. And its less code too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    var lis = $('#status li');
    lis.click(function() {
        lis.removeClass('active won-active');
        $(this).addClass('active')
    });

    lis.filter('.won').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('won-active')
    });
});
```

Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/smMT5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Similar code to jfriend00, just a little cleaner.  Assumes that no other code would set more than one active at a time...

```
$(function() { 
    $('#status li').click(function(){ 
        $(this).siblings().andSelf().toggleClass('active'); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  If you click on the active item, this will turn that one off and all others on.  I don't think that's what the OP wants.